# How to use the plugin aSimpleTour with the browser IE7?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I use

$.aSimpleTour(options);

but it does not work, there is a message error page in IE7

Comment: I found the problems...
First of all, in this section of code...

`tooltipColors : {      background: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.70)',      color: '#fff',    }`

remove the comma !

     `tooltipColors : {
      background: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.70)',
      color: '#fff' //,  <-- this
      }`


then the `rgba()` not working. Must be replaced by `rgb()`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the plugin does not have support for IE7, maybe IE8 will have.

Can you post the error sent by IE7?

Thanks!